# capturing this in nested lambdas

Tags: c++17

I have a question on the capture of `this` within nested lambdas. Within the innermost lambda why does this refer to `X` vs. the outer lambda? To be clear, I realize it does make sense for `this` to refer to the object of type `X` since since the (outer) lambda implementation is up to the compiler and capturing a reference to it is not meaningful. Can someone explain how the name `this` is propagated down the nested levels ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
struct X { 
    int x{};
    void func() { 
        vec.push_back([this]() {
            std::cout << "From outer lambda " << ++x << "\n";
            vec.push_back([this]() { std::cout << "From inner lambda " << ++x << "\n"; });
        });
    }
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> vec;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    X x;
    x.func();
    x.vec[0]();
    x.vec[1]();
}
```

```
Program stdout
From outer lambda 1
From inner lambda 2
```

Comment: What else could the inner `this` refer to?  The outer lambda is not a class member.  It doesn't have it's own `this`.  It only has the one that was bound, and that's a name it can pass along just like any other name.

Comment: CPP insights is very useful here https://cppinsights.io/s/2e01e4d4. However I don't fully follow line 36. It says ```__this->vec.push_back(std::function<void ()>(__lambda_9_27{this}));``` while it should actually be ```__this->vec.push_back(std::function<void ()>(__lambda_9_27{__this}));```? IOW the class ```__lambda_7_23``` cannot simply pass its own ```this``` pointer to the constructor of ```__lambda_9_27```.

Comment: I'm surprised by that, but perhaps that's just demonstrating the special treatment of `this`.  I would have surmised that the inner `this` was just reflecting the binding of the outer this, but perhaps the use of `this` anywhere in a method refers to the method `this`.